# Find not unique rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, having-clause

I have a question which looks easy but I can't figure it out.

I have the following:

```
   Name Zipcode

    ER 5354
    OL 1234
    AS 1234
    BH 3453
    BH 3453
    HZ 1234
```

I want to find those rows where the ID does not define clearly one row.

So here I want to see:

```
   OL 1234
   AS 1234
   HZ 1234
```

Or simply the zipcode enough.

**I am sorry I forget to mention an important part. If the name is the same its not a problem, only if there are different names for the same zipcode.**
So this means: BH 3453 does not return

Comment: What about `HZ 1234`? Why is this row not returned in your example?

Comment: sry my fault, it should return either

Comment: @Csanesz I've updated the query according to your update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
select zipcode
from yourTable
group by zipcode
having count(*) > 1
```

It selects the zipcodes associated to more than one record

to answer your updated question:

```
select zipcode
from
(
  select name, zipcode
  from yourTable
  group by name, zipcode
)
group by zipcode
having count(*) > 1
```

should do it. It might not be optimal in terms of performance in which case you could use window functions as suggested by @a1ex07

Comment: Be careful with name `table`, it's for the example but in this case use another name or use backticks. +1 for the solution

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Thanks for spotting this, I've updated the query

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select yt.*
  from YOUR_TABLE yt
     , (select zipcode
          from YOUR_TABLE
         group by zipcode
        having count(*) > 1
       ) m
 where yt.zipcode = m.zipcode
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need just zipcode, use **vc 74**'s solution. For all columns , solution based on window functions supposedly outperforms self join approach:

```
SELECT a.zipcode, a.name 
FROM 
(
   SELECT zipcode, name, count(1) over(partition by zipcode) as cnt
   FROM your_table
)a
WHERE a.cnt >1
```

Comment: Outperforms self join, but underperforms compared to simply using aggregate functions FIRST and LAST